# upload a 2.5Gb file

Tags: upload

In google cloud I have a storage and a segment where I copy a 2.5Gb file but it takes 15 hours. 
What configuration should the storage and the segment have to copy fast? .
To copy I use: gsutil cp filex gs: // namesegment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a 3 GB file:

```
    dd if=/dev/zero of=./gentoo_root.img bs=4k iflag=fullblock,count_bytes count=3G
```

For uploading to GCS you have some options:

1. You can use the gsutil tool transfers to enable a multi-threaded copy with -m flag:

   ```
   gsutil -m cp gentoo_root.img  gs://my-bucket/file.img
   ```
2. You can use gsutil with parallel composite uploads:

   ```
   gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M cp gentoo_root.img  gs://my-bucket/file.img
   ```
3. Or [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/)

You can find more information: [Strategies for transferring big data sets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime Google released the [`gcloud storage`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage) CLI which automatically optimizes the parallelization of uploads and downloads. For many situations the performance it delivers will cause you to reach some other bottheleck (network, host cpu, etc) and it beats `gsutil` for performance and ease of use every time.

For copying a file see the docs for [`gcloud storage cp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage/cp)

If you want to learn the pros/cons and how it parallelizes transfers read more in my recent blog post
[High throughput file transfers with Google Cloud Storage (GCS)](https://www.beginswithdata.com/2024/02/01/google-cloud-storage-max-throughput/).